# unable to cast System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText to System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, htmlgenericcontrol

I am trying to cast a htmlinputtext to a htmlgenericcontrol

file.aspx :

```
<form runat="server" class="probootstrap-form">         
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <label for="name">Markt Name:</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <input type="text" id="name" runat="server" required="required" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

file.aspx.cs :

```
HtmlGenericControl name = (HtmlGenericControl)Form.FindControl("name");
```

Error:  System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast an object of the typ "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText" into "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext?view=netframework-4.7.2) you can see that `HtmlInputText` does not inherit from `HtmlGenericControl` and thus is not able to cast to `HtmlGenericControl`

`HtmlInputText` would be able to cast to `HtmlInputControl`, `HtmlControl`, `Control` or `object` of which `Control` is the most generic that still makes sense in aspnet programming.